# Can we Delete Singleton class in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I wanted to delete singleton class
when i need
Could you please tell me is it possible to dispose or remove singleton class
from memory instance after use

Comment: Set the static instance to null and let the GC remove it on next run.

Answer (score 0):

Once the instance is disposed, it will be gone no matter if it is a singleton or not.